# what pattern should give inside http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET,"/api/jobs/find/**").hasAnyAuthority("APPLICANT"); in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security

My controller file is

```
***@GetMapping(path = "/jobs/find/{status}")
**    public ResponseEntity<List<Job>> getJActiveJobs(
            @PathVariable("status") String status)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity(jobService.getActiveJobs(status), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

`and in Securityconfig

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET,"/api/jobs/find/**").hasAnyAuthority("APPLICANT");
```

I have given this code.
on running 403 forbidden error is coming.

Comment: Considering your `@GetMapping` and antMatchers(**POST**,...)

Answer (score 0):

For example, your `controller`:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api") // (1)
class YourController {

   @GetMapping(path = "/jobs/find/{status}") (2)
   public void yourMethod() {
   ...
   }
}
```

The pattern includes (1) and (2), in this case, it would be your configuration `antMatchers("/api/jobs/find/**")`.